# Outlook 2013 ost data file location change

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I am trying to change location of OST data file. To using ForceOSTPath. But don't know why its not working for me. I also try to ad new account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **ForcePSTPath** regedit to change the default location of data file. While in outlook 2013 IMAP account data file is OST. But ForceOSTPath does not work for IMAP account.

Answer (score 1):

Happened for me as well once, with the mistake being I entered the ForceOSTPath in the wrong branch.

Also be aware that in order to change the OST path, you need to set up the e-mail account again—OST paths of existing account configurations cannot be changed.

1. Navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook
2. Create a dword [REG_EXPAND_SZ] value called ForceOSTPath
3. DoubleClick the newly created ForceOSTPath entry and enter the location to where you want to store the .ost file(s)
4. Reboot
5. In Control Panel, go to **Mail**, then click **E-mail Accounts**.
6. Choose your Exchange account and click **Change...**. Note down the server and user name, then cancel out of the dialog.
7. Click **Remove** to remove that account.
8. Click **New...** and set up a new Exchange account with the server and user name you just noted down. Set the check mark to modify settings and make sure the OST file is getting created in the correct location (if not, you can still change it at this point, but not afterwards).